# Software copyright infringement

Tags: reverse-engineering, portable-executable, ida

I've found a company in China selling a software that is clearly a copy of my own work. For context, this is actually a physical product that comes with a Ubuntu computer and the software pre-installed on it.

I've acquired this product and inspected some of the things. I see all the libraries are identical on their system as on my own. The auxiliary files used by the app are named identically as for my program. The format of these files are identical. And many other things that, in the end, for me, leave no doubt about the infringement.

But when I compared the executable binaries, I don't see any similarities when comparing byte for byte. I try reverse compiling my executable with Ida Pro, and I can do it. All the function and variable names are obfuscated but I can see the assembler code.
When I open my executable with Ida, a pop-up appears where I select that it's a "ELF64 for x86-x64 (Executable)".

When I open **their** executable in IdaPro, I get the same popup, but it doesn't offer me the option of ELF64. Instead, it just offers the option "Binary file".

[image: Opening the infringing executable with IdaPro]

When I press OK, I get this.

[image: 16bit or 32bit mode]

I press Yes, I finally get this.

[image: Where's the entry point?]

I press OK, and then I see a hex view of the literal bytes in the executable. And I'm supposed to find the entry point?

I'm not even mad, this is great job. I wish I knew how to protect my code in this way.

1. Is there a way that they could have used my executable and then somehow re-compiled it so that it's different but still be able to execute?
2. How would you go about gathering proofs of infringement from a technical standpoint. That is, I'm not looking for an opinion from a Law expert. Just from a technical standpoint, I see binary similarity as the best form of evidence of infringement.

EDIT: I'm sharing the first segment of my own app vs the copied app.

My app:

```
7F 45 4C 46 02 01 01 03 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
02 00 3E 00 01 00 00 00 90 F7 42 00 00 00 00 00
40 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 D0 14 52 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 40 00 38 00 0A 00 40 00 21 00 20 00
06 00 00 00 05 00 00 00 40 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
40 00 40 00 00 00 00 00 40 00 40 00 00 00 00 00
30 02 00 00 00 00 00 00 30 02 00 00 00 00 00 00
08 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 03 00 00 00 04 00 00 00
70 02 00 00 00 00 00 00 70 02 40 00 00 00 00 00
70 02 40 00 00 00 00 00 1C 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
1C 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
01 00 00 00 05 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 40 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 40 00 00 00 00 00
A9 82 51 00 00 00 00 00 A9 82 51 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 20 00 00 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 06 00 00 00
B8 89 51 00 00 00 00 00 B8 89 B1 00 00 00 00 00
B8 89 B1 00 00 00 00 00 B4 89 00 00 00 00 00 00
78 6D 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 20 00 00 00 00 00
02 00 00 00 06 00 00 00 78 F9 51 00 00 00 00 00
78 F9 B1 00 00 00 00 00 78 F9 B1 00 00 00 00 00
20 05 00 00 00 00 00 00 20 05 00 00 00 00 00 00
08 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 04 00 00 00 04 00 00 00
8C 02 00 00 00 00 00 00 8C 02 40 00 00 00 00 00
8C 02 40 00 00 00 00 00 44 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
44 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 04 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
07 00 00 00 04 00 00 00 B8 89 51 00 00 00 00 00
B8 89 B1 00 00 00 00 00 B8 89 B1 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 10 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
08 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 50 E5 74 64 04 00 00 00
30 A9 4C 00 00 00 00 00 30 A9 8C 00 00 00 00 00
30 A9 8C 00 00 00 00 00 1C 77 00 00 00 00 00 00
1C 77 00 00 00 00 00 00 04 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
51 E5 74 64 06 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
```

Infringing app:

```
2a c5 e6 c6 57 fc ab fe 55 ff aa ff 55 ff aa ff 
57 fd 94 fd 54 fe aa fe 95 c9 e8 3f 55 ff aa ff 
15 bf aa bf 55 ff aa ff fd 83 fb 57 55 ff aa ff 
55 ff aa ff 15 bf 92 bf 5f f5 ea f5 75 df b5 df 
53 f9 aa f9 51 fb aa fb 15 bf aa bf 55 ff aa ff 
15 bf ea bf 55 ff aa ff 15 bf ea bf 55 ff aa ff 
65 cd aa cf 55 ff aa ff 65 cd aa cf 55 ff aa ff 
5d f7 aa f7 55 ff aa ff 56 fc aa fc 51 fb aa fb 
25 8d aa 8f 55 ff aa ff 25 8d ea 8f 55 ff aa ff 
25 8d ea 8f 55 ff aa ff 49 e3 aa e3 55 ff aa ff 
49 e3 aa e3 55 ff aa ff 54 fe aa fe 55 ff aa ff 
54 fe aa fe 50 fa aa fa 55 ff aa ff 55 ff aa ff 
55 ff ea ff 55 ff aa ff 55 ff ea ff 55 ff aa ff 
7c e4 fb d6 55 ff aa ff 7c e4 fb d6 55 ff aa ff 
55 ff 8a ff 55 ff aa ff 54 fe aa fe 53 f9 aa f9 
8d 66 fb 27 55 ff aa ff 8d 66 1b 27 55 ff aa ff 
8d 66 1b 27 55 ff aa ff 29 12 aa 83 55 ff aa ff 
0d cd ab a7 55 ff aa ff 55 ff 8a ff 55 ff aa ff 
57 fd aa fd 53 f9 aa f9 35 24 fb 9f 55 ff aa ff 
35 24 1b 9f 55 ff aa ff 35 24 1b 9f 55 ff aa ff 
a5 0d aa 0f 55 ff aa ff a5 0d aa 0f 55 ff aa ff 
5d f7 aa f7 55 ff aa ff 51 fb aa fb 51 fb aa fb 
d9 71 aa 73 55 ff aa ff d9 71 ea 73 55 ff aa ff 
d9 71 ea 73 55 ff aa ff 11 bb aa bb 55 ff aa ff 
11 bb aa bb 55 ff aa ff 51 fb aa fb 55 ff aa ff 
52 f8 aa f8 51 fb aa fb 8d 66 fb 27 55 ff aa ff 
8d 66 1b 27 55 ff aa ff 8d 66 1b 27 55 ff aa ff 
55 ff aa ff 55 ff aa ff 45 ef aa ef 55 ff aa ff 
5d f7 aa f7 55 ff aa ff 05 4a de cb 51 fb aa fb 
f5 c1 e6 5f 55 ff aa ff f5 c1 26 5f 55 ff aa ff 
f5 c1 26 5f 55 ff aa ff 69 b6 aa c3 55 ff aa ff 
69 b6 aa c3 55 ff aa ff 51 fb aa fb 55 ff aa ff 
04 4b de ca 53 f9 aa f9 55 ff aa ff 55 ff aa ff
```

It looks like it's xorred with some pattern but not quite. Also, they might have started with a slightly different version of my code. Depending on the exact build they used.

Comment: Try [opensource.se] or [law.se]. Legal questions are [explicitly off-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) on StackOverflow.

Comment: Just about everything installed by default on Ubuntu (as well as any other Linux distribution) is *open source* or *free software*. You can easily find out what package the program is installed from, and from that find out the source and authors. No reverse engineering needed.

Comment: I wouldn't put too much effort into analysing their code, prosecuting software licence infringement is going to be very difficult in china. At best you might get an import ban but even that's likely to be difficult to enforce

Comment: If their executable is not PE, what format is it? If this is not an easy question for you, you may have to rethink your reverse-engineering activity.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen, the first question is hardly a legal one?

Comment: Re 1: I'm sure there are tools that take a binary and output a different binary with the same behavior (normally with a goal of optimizing it). [BOLT](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/tree/main/bolt), various binary packers, etc.

Comment: @teapot418 For simplicity, just imagine some other alternative format and say that this is their format. What would be the next step?

Comment: When you have identified the format, use some tools that can deal with the format. You mention Ubuntu, which has ELF executables, you can take those apart e.g. with objdump.

Comment: Given its on Linux a PE executable would be surprising given that's the windows format. I'd guess it's ELF instead?

Comment: @AlanBirtles Yes, this is strange to mee, too. Why it even mentions PE? This free version of Ida I'm using clearly supports formats other than PE. Otherwise, how would it work with a binary I compile with gcc on ubuntu?

Comment: Given IDA is a commercial product you might want to reach out to them if you have an issue

Comment: the question is closed but yet intriguing.. what made me trigger (and I'm not the only one in the comments) is the PE issue. You talked about an Ubuntu machine but yet you are using IDA (for Windows) and that last detail makes me assume your work is compiled for Windows. But the target you are decompiling is probably an ELF executable not a PE (exe). Unless it was running under Wine. But yet Windows binaries would call Windows apis.. anyway it was just splitting the hairs. It's strange IDA warned you because it can decompile ELFs as well

Comment: @DiegoD, I'm using Ida for Linux. I still don't know why Ida is mentioning PE format.

Comment: ok I did a wrong assumption based on that message then. The only guess I can make is that version of IDA you have doesn't allow decompiling format different from PE. But it was said already so I didn't add anything new. Talking about infringement it depends on how you licensed your code.. but yet that's a matter for another type of forum. All this question is addressing here is how to find out if a binary contains code you can compare with another source. Just to narrow down the scope

Comment: @DiegoD Yes. Also, if I built my C++ with GCC on Ubuntu and I successfully decompiled it with Ida on that same machine. Does that mean the GCC on Ubuntu produced a PE file?

Comment: the compiler spits out a binary according to the target you specified when you ran the compiler. a PE file is an .exe file suited to run on windows. Its format can be easily recognized watching the first few bytes on an hex editor. Judging from your question I assume you compiled an elf binary and then you successfully decompiled it with IDA. So again I don't understand how that version will say 'not a PE file' in the first scenario. Why it was expecting a PE file since it said not a PE file??? and yet successfully worked with an elf in your test?

Comment: I'm not a deep expert of this matter... but this detail triggered me to the point of asking things to better understand the scenario in details

Comment: What does the ubuntu `file` command say on their file?

Comment: If I run ```file x```, it says ```x: data```

Comment: So "binary blob, no recognizable header". Does it have recognizable strings inside? (command `strings`) yes->no idea (they have some custom loader?); no->encrypted/compressed?

Comment: I also agree that it's very strange.. maybe sharing further info like the first dozens bytes would help better understand. There's something you never perfectly said nor in the question and neither in comments.. what's this file?? are you sure is an executable? does it actually run? and does it run on linux with no wine involved? because once that's given for granted you can start narrowing down why the analysys doesn't recognize its nature. Maybe there's a shebang in the beginning triggering a custom loader??

Comment: Their binary doesn't look like a natural arrangement of bytes. The '55 ff aa' sequences in there probably represent zeros. So some sort of obfuscation encoding. As it's double in size, it may not be obvious which bytes to XOR together, especially if you're not sure of the version used. (is one of yours exactly half in size?)

Comment: @teapot418 Sorry, I forgot to edit that part of the question. This part was wrong, I removed it now. Their binary is of almost the same size as mine. Something like ~32 bytes difference.